# Two versions of modx on one hosting

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

I have an old version of the site on modx **evolution**. There is one extension for polls, which has version only for **evolution**.

The current version of the site is based on modx **revolution** and it hasn't this extension (or analogues). I want use extension on the old site, but I need integrate it with new site's database (for example, I will use users' table etc.) How I can do that?

Usecase has the following appereance:

- User, who authorized on the new site, go on the old site, do some
  actions.
- Old version writes result of his action to own database.
- New version will take this result to own database (how?)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds complicated what you are trying to achieve. There is a [poll add-on for MODX Revolution](https://modx.com/extras/package/polls), so you might not need this complicated solution. Don't know if it works with the newest MODX 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for responce. I don't need a one voteable question, I need set pack of questions, tune weight of every answer variant and output result of this (amount of correct answers, mistakes and other statistics)